# Python Ignore MySQL IntegrityError when trying to add duplicate entry with a Primary key

Tags: python, mysql, sql

So I have a string in Python that contains like 500 SQL INSERT queries, separated by `;`. This is purely for performance reasons, otherwise I would execute individual queries and I wouldn't have this problem.

When I run my SQL query, Python throws: `IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'http://domain.com' for key 'PRIMARY'")`

Lets say on the first query of 500, the error is thrown. How can I make sure those other 499 queries are executed on my database?

If I used a try and except, sure the exception wouldn't be raised, but the rest of my statement wouldn't be executed. Or would it, since Python sends it all in 1 big combined string to MySQL?

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried it?  for that matter, are you sure that sending 500 queries in one string actually improves performance?  why not just insert 500 rows with one query?  does `INSERT IGNORE` do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that cares, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` SQL command was what I ended up using.